# jQuery Deferred a loop with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred, deferred

I currently have an application that depends on all data being retrieved then proceed with further code.

There is a primary function "_update()" that contains a loop, this loop calls _getData(). I need "_update()" to set a variable to true when all data has been received.

Here is what I have:

```
DataCollection.prototype._update = function () {
    var _self = this;
    var _itemsResponded = 0;
    var itemData = [];

    if (_self._ready) {
        _self._ready = false;

        this.collection.forEach(function (item, index) {
            _self.apiData.id = item.id;

            var ajaxPromise = _self._getData();
            ajaxPromise.done(function(data){
                itemData[index] = data;
                _self._itemsResponded++;
            });
        })

        if (_self._itemsResponded === _self.collection.length) {
            _self._ready = true;
            console.log(itemData);
            console.log('done');
        }
    }
}

DataCollection.prototype._getData = function () {
    var _self = this;

    var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data : _self.apiData,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    var dff = $.Deferred();
    ajaxPromise.then(function(data) {
        dff.resolve(data);
    }, function(){
        dff.reject();
    });

    return dff.promise();
}
```

From my understanding, the _getData function is working correctly. It's the .forEach in _update that does not work as expected. I thought .forEach was synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents of the forEach() method is async, the foreach loop will finish executing before all the ajax request are completed, so your check should go inside the done callback like

```
DataCollection.prototype._update = function () {
    var _self = this;
    var _itemsResponded = 0;
    var itemData = [];

    if (_self._ready) {
        _self._ready = false;

        this.collection.forEach(function (item, index) {
            _self.apiData.id = item.id;

            var ajaxPromise = _self._getData();
            ajaxPromise.done(function (data) {
                itemData[index] = data;
                _self._itemsResponded++;

                if (_self._itemsResponded === _self.collection.length) {
                    _self._ready = true;
                    console.log(itemData);
                    console.log('done');
                }
            });
        })
    }
}
```

---

You can use $.when() to simplify this to

```
DataCollection.prototype._update = function () {
    var _self = this;
    var _itemsResponded = 0;
    var itemData = [];

    if (_self._ready) {
        _self._ready = false;

        var promises = $.map(this.collection, function (item, index) {
            _self.apiData.id = item.id;
            return _self._getData();
        });

        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
            var itemData = $.map(arguments, function (arr, idx) {
                return arr[0];
            })
            _self._ready = true;
            console.log(itemData);
            console.log('done');
        })
    }
}

DataCollection.prototype._getData = function () {
    var _self = this;

    var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: _self.apiData,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    return ajaxPromise;
}
```

Comment: Inside the $.when(), you pass "arguments" to the map. What is this variable?

Comment: @Stoyvo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments